# Setting PHP Document Root on webserver

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

Currently I have an Ubuntu 12.04 webserver running apache2. I have it setup to dynamically create subdomains by creating new folders under /sites/example.com/*/public /sites/example.com/www/public is reserved for my main root site.

This is working out, however I am unable to configure PHP's `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to be dynamic to the newly created folder.

When I echo `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` I get */etc/apache2/htdocs* which I assume is some sort of default path. I would like this to be: /sites/example.com/*/public instead

```
# Wildcards
<VirtualHost *:80>
    VirtualDocumentRoot /sites/example.com/%1/public
    ServerAdmin mike@example.com
    ServerAlias *.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Curious why PHP doesn't pick up the the virtual document root setting above, I'm likely doing something wrong.

Comment: Are you confident that files are being served out of the proper DocumentRoot at /sites/example.com/*/public? What is the path of the PHP file you're testing with, and what Host are you using to obtain it?

Comment: Yea, the rest of the php stuff is executing as I expected. It seems that this variable can vary per host. This seems to do the trick, but I don't know if its the best solution (http://joshbenner.me/blog/quick-tip-get-proper-document-root-when-using-mod-vhost-alias/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solution found at : http://joshbenner.me/blog/quick-tip-get-proper-document-root-when-using-mod-vhost-alias/

> The Apache module mod_vhost_alias and its VirtualDocumentRoot
>   directive can really be a great time saver for local development (some
>   googling will explain why in more deapth). Basically, my local dev is
>   set up so that I just have to create a directory in my aliases
>   directory, and I just then navigate my browser to a URL matching the
>   name of that new directory, and apache knows exactly what to serve
>   automagically.
>
> However, there are a few evil gotchas when using mod_vhost_alias, one
>   of which is that the PHP global $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] remains set
>   to the apache default DOCUMENT_ROOT environment variable rather than
>   being re-assigned to the document root activated by the
>   VirtualDocumentRoot directive for the current URL. This can cause some
>   PHP applications (that are too trusting) to die for one reason or
>   another.
>
> I found a great solution to this in the related apache bug report:
>   Simply add the following line to your apache configuration inside the
>   VirtualDocumentRoot vhost definition:
>
> php_admin_value auto_prepend_file /path/setdocroot.php
>
> Then, create the referenced PHP file, and put set this as its
>   contents:
>
> ```
> <?php $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = str_replace($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']); ?>
> ```
>
> Now, every page load has this file executed, which properly sets
>   DOCUMENT_ROOT.

Comment: I did this and set `php_admin_value auto_prepend_file /sites/example.com/_setdocroot.php` It does what I need it to.

Answer (score 1):

This has apparently (finally) [been fixed](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=26052) in Apache 2.4.  Unfortunately, Ubuntu 12.04 still runs Apache 2.2.

Having said that, Ubuntu 14.04 (the next LTS release) is out now and `do-release-upgrade` should now be enabled for 12.04 to 14.04 upgrades since 14.04 had its first point release [last week](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2014-July/000188.html).